# SQL Server 2012 dynamic pivot - concatenation for cross tab

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crosstab

Can I use a concatenation as the cross tab variable in a dynamic pivot?

I'm trying to generate a cross tab table of values of transactions, where the column headers are [yyyy-mm] in date order based on a [transaction date] date field.

This is the data:-

```
 RW_Ref     ,Transaction_Date  ,Transaction_Type ,Transaction_Value ,Batch_Number ,Month
     1    ,  03/09/2009              ,11              ,30               ,999   
     1     , 05/10/2009              ,11              ,25               ,999 
     1     , 11/10/2009              ,11              ,15               ,999
     1     , 15/11/2009              ,11              ,40               ,999
     1     , 03/12/2009              ,11              ,30               ,999   
     2     , 05/10/2009              ,11              ,60               ,999 
     2     , 11/11/2009              ,11              ,70               ,999
     2     , 01/12/2009              ,11              ,60               ,999
     2     , 03/12/2009              ,11              ,15               ,999   
     3     , 05/11/2009              ,11              ,25               ,999
     3     , 06/11/2009              ,11              ,35               ,999
     3     , 07/11/2009              ,11              ,60               ,999
```

And this is what I'm trying to get back:-

```
Transaction_Type,Batch_Number,[2009-09],[2009-10],[2009-11],[2009-12]
11              ,999         ,30       ,40       ,40       ,30       
11              ,999         ,         ,60       ,70       ,75       
11              ,999         ,         ,         ,120      ,
```

This is the code I've got so far:-

```
DECLARE     @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select      @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' 
        + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(datepart(yyyy,[Transaction_Date]) , '-', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), datepart(M,[Transaction_Date])), 2)))
                from [TX].[dbo].[Transactions] ORDER by 1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
       ,1,1,'')

set @query = 
'SELECT [RW_Ref], [Transaction_Type], [Transaction_Value], [Batch_Number], ' 
         + @cols 
         + ' ' 
         +'FROM [TX].[dbo].[Transactions] 
               PIVOT (
                   SUM([Transaction_Value])
              FOR
                   CONCAT(
                   datepart(yyyy,[Transaction_Date]), ' 
                   + QUOTENAME('-','''') 
                       + ', RIGHT(' + QUOTENAME('00','''') + ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), datepart(M,[Transaction_Date])), 2))
               ) p '
 print @query

 execute(@query)
```

The Print @Query produces this:-

```
SELECT [RW_Ref], [Transaction_Type], [Transaction_Value], [Batch_Number],  [2009-09], [2009-10], [2009-11], [2009-12], [2016-07] FROM [TX].[dbo].[Transactions] 
PIVOT (
SUM([Transaction_Value]) 
FOR
CONCAT(
datepart(yyyy,[Transaction_Date]), '-', 
RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), datepart(M,[Transaction_Date])), 2))
) p
```

but this generates a message 
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
    Incorrect syntax near '('. 
Line 5 is the CONCAT( I think. Can I use the Concat fun ction to generate the column headings in this way or do I have to use a record only (which means I need to add that field as a column which I'd rather not do, it's not my table)

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) sugguests SQL Server is expecting a named column after the FOR and a list of pivoted columns after the IN.  This cannot be parameterised directly.  You'll need the dynamic SQL to calculate these as it populates the @query var.

Comment: I think the syntax of PIVOT should be PIVOT(SUM([...]) FOR <column_name> IN (value1, value2,...)) p. The @Query string above seems to violate that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following code?
EDIT: you need original date values both in select and in statements. You have to modify your "select @cols = ..." part of the query to return original values (get rid of the datepart stuff in the column) as column names and alias them as you wish. The IN operator requires full values.

```
    set @query = 
'SELECT [RW_Ref], [Transaction_Type], [Batch_Number], ' 
         + @cols 
         + ' ' 
         +'FROM [TX].[dbo].[Transactions] 
               PIVOT (
                   SUM([Transaction_Value])
              FOR

                   [Transaction_Date] IN ( ' 
                   + @cols + ')
               ) p '
```

Please let me know if it works. See an example below, which you can run on TSQL2012 sample database, it should help you understand how the pivot statement works.

```
select shipperid, [2006-07-29 00:00:00.000] as '2006/07', [2006-08-12 00:00:00.000] as '2006/08'
from sales.orders
pivot (sum (freight) for shippeddate in ([2006-07-29 00:00:00.000], [2006-08-12 00:00:00.000])) as p
```

Comment: Thanks. That works :o) However it creates a table with a column for each day,which is what I was trying to avoid. At least I understand dynamic pivots now enough to know I can't use it for this, I'll have to use another approach.

Comment: I think you could try writing a subquery which would group transactions by months and then use it for pivoting.