# SQL Server - Dynamic Pivot using existing table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following query

```
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Procedures.SeriesNum),2),'-',RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Procedures.ProcNum),4)) AS 'Procedure',
Procedures.Description,
Procedures.CurrentRev,
Procedures.DayToDayLevel,
Procedures.MaxLevel,
Users.Username,
UsersProcedures.RevTrained,
UsersProcedures.LevelTrained
FROM Procedures
CROSS JOIN Users
LEFT JOIN UsersProcedures ON UsersProcedures.Username = Users.Username AND Procedures.SeriesNum = UsersProcedures.SeriesNum AND Procedures.ProcNum = UsersProcedures.ProcNum
```

Which returns the following results:
[image: Results]
However I would like to use a Pivot so that the info for each user (Specifically The Level they were trained at is shown as a value in a column (With the column title being that of the username).

I would like to ignore the CurrentRev, and instead have 1 row for each Revision for each procedure (if no users have been trained to the current revision - whether users have been trained to any previous revisions on that procedure or not, that should be there as an empty row), like below:

[image]

I presume I need to use a pivot, although i've never attempted it before, plus the examples i've seen on the web seem to use a static list for the pivoted columns, whereas I want to use all records in the Users table.

I should point out, when it comes to displaying the results in a datagrid, it'll be coloured for clarity.

How would I go about attempting this?

UPDATE: I've got as far as this query

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Procedures.SeriesNum),2),'-',RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Procedures.ProcNum),4)) AS 'Procedure',
Procedures.Description,
Procedures.CurrentRev,
UsersProcedures.RevTrained,
Users.Username,
UsersProcedures.LevelTrained FROM Procedures CROSS JOIN Users LEFT JOIN UsersProcedures ON UsersProcedures.Username = Users.Username AND Procedures.SeriesNum = UsersProcedures.SeriesNum AND Procedures.ProcNum = UsersProcedures.ProcNum) AS Procs
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(LevelTrained)
    FOR Procs.Username
    IN(User1,User2,User3)
  ) AS PivotTable
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

However i'd still like to group the results further similar to my 2nd screenshot. i.e. if at least 1 user has already been trained on a particular revision, then don't show another empty row for that revision as well.

Also if RevTrained is NULL, then show CurrentRev in its place.

Comment: Yes, you need dynamic pivot for it. It takes some work. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270987/sql-server-2012-dynamic-pivot-concatenation-for-cross-tab/38271962#38271962) for some insight. I will try to find some more time to help you in a bit.

Comment: I should add that all the examples I can find involve aggregating the Pivot data, but I don't actually want to do that. It's a single value (the Training Level for that procedure & it's revision) that I want to display per user.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the finished solution, using a dynamic query to get all the users, and an IF statement to solve the above problems:

> If at least 1 user has already been trained on a particular revision, then don't show another empty row for that revision as well.
>   Also if RevTrained is NULL, then show CurrentRev in its place.

```
DECLARE @users AS VARCHAR(MAX),@query AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @users  = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONCAT('[',Username,']') FROM Users FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
SET @query = 'SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(''00'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Procedures.SeriesNum),2),''-'',RIGHT(''0000'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Procedures.ProcNum),4)) AS ''Procedure Number'',
CASE WHEN UsersProcedures.RevTrained IS NULL THEN Procedures.CurrentRev ELSE UsersProcedures.RevTrained END AS ''Revision'',
Procedures.Description,
Procedures.DayToDayLevel AS ''Maxmimum Training Level'',
Procedures.DayToDayLevel AS ''Training level for Day to Day Usage'', 
Users.Username,
UsersProcedures.LevelTrained FROM Procedures CROSS JOIN Users LEFT JOIN UsersProcedures ON UsersProcedures.Username = Users.Username AND Procedures.SeriesNum = UsersProcedures.SeriesNum AND Procedures.ProcNum = UsersProcedures.ProcNum) AS Procs
PIVOT(
MAX(LevelTrained)
FOR Procs.Username
IN('+@users+')) AS PivotTable'
execute(@query);
```